# Not enough memory/code running slow

Tags: r, memory

On the final line of my code, I get an error saying there's not enough memory. Any help would be appreciated! I am trying to find all combinations you can assemble a team of 9 players, with 2 chosen from group 1 through 4, and 1 chosen from group 5. After finding all combinations, I want to find all combinations below a given salary threshold.

```
pg.number= 1:10
sg.number= 11:20
sf.number= 21:30
pf.number=31:40
c.number=41:50

pg.combos= combn(pg.number, 2)
sg.combos= combn(sg.number,2)
sf.combos= combn(sf.number, 2)
pf.combos= combn(pf.number, 2)
c.combos= combn(c.number, 1)


replicate.vec= function(vector,matrix.1) {
  empty.matrix<- matrix(vector, nrow=length(vector), ncol= ncol(matrix.1))
  rbind(matrix.1, empty.matrix)
}


list<- as.list(numeric(ncol(sg.combos)))
for (i in 1:ncol(sg.combos)) {
  list[[i]]=replicate.vec(sg.combos[,i],pg.combos)
}
pg.and.sg<-as.matrix(do.call(cbind,list))

list<- as.list(numeric(ncol(sf.combos)))
for (i in 1:ncol(sf.combos)) {
  list[[i]]=replicate.vec(sf.combos[,i],pg.and.sg)
}
pg.sg.sf<-as.matrix(do.call(cbind,list))


list<- as.list(numeric(ncol(pf.combos)))
for (i in 1:ncol(pf.combos)) {
  list[[i]]=replicate.vec(pf.combos[,i],pg.sg.sf)
}
pg.sg.sf.pf<-as.matrix(do.call(cbind,list))


list<- as.list(numeric(ncol(c.combos)))
for (i in 1:ncol(c.combos)) {
  list[[i]]=replicate.vec(c.combos[,i],pg.sg.sf.pf)
}
all.lineups<-as.matrix(do.call(cbind,list))
all.lineups


c1<- 1:50
c2<- rnorm(50)
c3<- rnorm(50, mean=100)
c4<- rnorm(50)
df<- data.frame(cbind(c1,c2,c3,c4))

get.fantasy.salary<- function(vector) {
  sum(df[vector,3])
}

get.fantasy.points<- function(vector) {
  sum(df[vector,4])
}
sum.salary<-apply(all.lineups,2, get.fantasy.salary)
```

Comment: Why don't you just take the players with the lowest salary from each group?

Comment: @marat I made an edit to my post. I'd like to find all combinations below a given salary threshold.

Comment: Perhaps some clever maths would help more than clever programming.  Have you considered MathOverflow for some kind of optimal algorithm?

Comment: I would recommend looking into the `bigmemory` package to deal with your apply -- could be a quick fix to attempt the apply on a `big.matrix.class` instead of the plain matrix.

Answer (score 0):

`apply(,2)` is slow. Instead, you can use

```
salary.lineups <- matrix(df[all.lineups,3],nrow=9)
colSums(salary.lineups)
```